# Error "Must declare the scalar variable" when creating a stored procedure with table parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

When creating a stored procedure, with a table parameter, and attempting to use the parameter in a join, I get the error: Must declare the scalar variable "@tokens".

Can you please tell me what I need to do to to use the parameter in the join?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc] @tokens [TokenTable] readonly
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE DN
SET DN.Deleted = 1
FROM [dbo].[DeviceNotificationTokens] DN
JOIN @tokens ON DN.Token = @tokens.Token AND DN.Provider = @tokens.Provider
END
```

Comment: Try giving `@tokens` an alias, like `t` or something in your join. I think it's upset that you're trying to qualify a column with a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an alias when joining to a TVP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc] @tokens [TokenTable] readonly
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE DN
SET DN.Deleted = 1
FROM [dbo].[DeviceNotificationTokens] DN
JOIN @tokens t
    ON DN.Token = t.Token AND DN.Provider = t.Provider
END
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The following Transact-SQL UPDATE statement demonstrates how to use a
>   table-valued parameter by joining it to the Categories table. **When you
>   use a table-valued parameter with a JOIN in a FROM clause, you must
>   also alias it**, as shown here, where the table-valued parameter is
>   aliased as "ec":
>
> ```
> UPDATE dbo.Categories
>     SET Categories.CategoryName = ec.CategoryName
>     FROM dbo.Categories INNER JOIN @tvpEditedCategories AS ec
>     ON dbo.Categories.CategoryID = ec.CategoryID;
> ```